# Importing .csv into Google Sheets: incorrect conversion

Tags: csv, google-sheets

Sorry for this seemingly stupid question but I'm new to Google Sheets and I cannot for the love of my life find an answer to this.

I'm trying to import a semi-colon separated .csv file to Google Sheets. Upon doing so, it immediately separates the columns correctly, and 1 second later it converts again into a bunch of strange characters which look the same but cannot be replaced/removed using CTRL+F. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I see the normal text, but with one extra character between every normal character, which makes me think your file is not UTF-8 encoded. If you CSV isn't too big, open it in a text editor and verify its _encoding_ is UTF-8. If you're on Windows, Notepad++ will you show you the encoding at the bottom of the Window. VS code also can show and modify encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode each cell with

```
function utf8decode(utftext) {
  var string = "";
  var i = 0;
  var c = c1 = c2 = 0;
  while ( i < utftext.length ) {
    c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);
    if (c < 128) {
      string += String.fromCharCode(c);
      i++;
    }
    else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
      c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
      string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
      i += 2;
    }
    else {
      c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
      c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
      string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
      i += 3;
    }
  }
  return string;
}
```